# Downgrade my react-native-cli version from 2.0.1 to 1.2.0

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I wanted to downgrade my react-native-cli version from **2.0.1 to 1.2.0**. This is because I have a react-native project which is my colleague running react-native-cli 1.2.0 without having any issue. So to do the debugging, i need to downgrade the version to check if this cause the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have to install an older version of a package, just specify it

`npm install <package>@<version>`

For your case: `npm install react-native-cli@1.2.0`

**EDIT**

If you have installed a version of it already uninstall by `npm uninstall -g react-native-cli` and do the above

Comment: its not working.. still showing me the latest version

Comment: Uninstall it by `npm uninstall -g react-native-cli` and do the above

Comment: u can edit your answer then i will accept yours.. uninstall then install again with -g

Answer (score 1):

Check package.json and change the version like `"react-native": "0.44.3",` to `"react-native": "0.44.0",` and change the `node_module` name. This will save your time to remove `node_module`. After all of above things run `npm install`.